# Android facebook SDK 4.x getting user email without JSON

Tags: android, facebook, email

I want to ask how could I get user's which is logged into app email as string value? I have only seen tutorials how to get it using json and then send it to web service which I don't need. Maybe someone could show me the simple way of getting user email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Graph API always returns JSON. So, no, I don't think that this is possible. The Android SDK provides convenience classes, so I don't really see a big effort using those. You can use `JSONObject.get("email")` to retrieve to value of the email property I guess.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph#userdata
- http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#get(java.lang.String)